# How to use $httpBackend.passThrough() with Karma unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I've looked up and down and tried all kinds of things to make the E2E passThrough() actually work. Only examples are for templates. I don't think it actually can work but if someone has ever seen a working example I would love to see it.  Basically I want real XHR calls in my Karma tests instead of mocks.

This is where I am at - i've tried a bunch of variations - right now I get an Unknown provider: cartServiceProvider error - sometimes I get that injected but then it's something else.

```
myAppDev = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E']);
myAppDev.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^api\/cart\/save/).passThrough();
});
beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$http_e) {
  $scope = _$rootScope_;
  $http = _$http_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

}));

describe('#createOrder()', function() {
  it('should return an order ID', function(done) {
    inject(function(cartService) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        cartService.createOrder(function(res) {
          done();
        });
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Sample service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('cartService', function($http) {

  Cart.prototype.createOrder = function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    var data = {}

    $http.post('/api/cart/save', data ).success(function(res) {
      self.order = res.id;
      callback(res);
    });
  };
```